# Inlining a rvar to a var stage in Halide

Tags: halide

I’m trying to inline a rvar to a regular var stage.

Let’s say I have an input vector of some size, which I would like to multiply each element by 2, as well as sum all of its elements.

something like :

```
Input<Buffer<int>> vector {“vector”, 1};
Output<Buffer<int>> output {“output”, 1}
Output<Func> sum_elements {“sum_elements”, Int(32), 0};

Var i;
RDom r(0, vector.length());
output(i) = 2 * vector(i);
sum_elements() = 0;
sum_elements() += vector(r.x);
```

I would like to know if its possible to schedule sum_elements to be computed along output, even if not optimal:

```
output.compute_root(); // or any other form of schedule

// somehow create a link between r.x and i, and then:

sum_elements.update().compute_with(output, i);
```

so the equivalent c would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.length(); ++i)
{
    output(i) = 2 * vector (i);
    sum_elements() += vector (i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach that might be acceptable is to use the `RDom` to also define the `output`:

```cpp
Input<Buffer<int>> vector {“vector”, 1};
Output<Buffer<int>> output {“output”, 1}
Output<Func> sum_elements {“sum_elements”, Int(32), 0};

Var i;
RDom r(0, vector.length());
output(i) = 0;
output(r.x) = 2 * vector(r.x) + 0 * output(r.x - 1);
sum_elements() = 0;
sum_elements() += vector(r.x);

output.compute_root();
sum_elements.compute_root();
sum_elements.update().compute_with(output.update(), r.x);
```

Note that without the no-op `0 * output(r.x - 1)`, the above would fail with the following error message:

```
Invalid compute_with: types of dim 0 of output.s1(r5$x is PureRVar)
and sum_elements.s1(r5$x is ImpureRVar) do not match.
```

There is probably a more elegant way to fix this, but the workaround is effectively removed during compilation. It seems to turn the use of the `RVar` into something impure (my knowledge of the difference between `PureRVar` and `ImpureRVar` is limited, unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks! I noticed the workaround initializes the output vector with zeros, so to avoid this I replaced ouput(i) = 0; with output(i) = undef<int>();